# Excel/VBA IF statement works incorrect

Tags: vba, excel

I have problem with IF's, when I checked checkbox which is disable then function still color my row. The solution which I'm trying get is that for checked checkbox row is green and for unchecked is blank or other color.

here is my code:

```
Sub CheckBoxDate()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim chk As CheckBox
Dim lColD As Long
Dim lColChk As Long
Dim lRow As Long

Dim rngD As Range
lColD = 0 'number of columns to the right for date

Set ws = Sheets("MA Template_VBack-End")
Set chk = ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
lRow = chk.TopLeftCell.Row
lColChk = chk.TopLeftCell.Column
Set rngD = ws.Cells(lRow, lColChk + lColD)


Select Case chk.Value
   Case 1   'box is checked

  For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes

If ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("D" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("E" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("f" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("g" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("i" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("t" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("u" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("z" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ab" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ac" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ap" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("at" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bt" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bu" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
   rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

 ElseIf ws.Range("bv" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bx" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bz" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ca" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cc" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cd" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ce" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ci" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ck" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cl" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cm" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cn" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("co" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cp" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cq" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
    chk.Value = False
 rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf ws.Range("ea" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ed" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ee" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eg" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eh" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ei" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ej" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
  rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed

Else
rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 chk.Value = True


End If

Next chk

   Case Else   'box is not checked
   chk.Enabled = True
      rngD.ClearContents
      rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Select

End Sub
```

Main problem should be here, i'm not sure if i use correct if in case

```
Select Case chk.Value
   Case 1   'box is checked

  For Each chk In ws.CheckBoxes

If ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("D" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("E" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("f" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("g" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("i" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("t" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("u" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("z" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ab" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ac" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ap" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("at" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bt" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bu" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
   rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

 ElseIf ws.Range("bv" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bx" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bz" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ca" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cc" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cd" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ce" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ci" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ck" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cl" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cm" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cn" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("co" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cp" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cq" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
    chk.Value = False
 rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf ws.Range("ea" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ed" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ee" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eg" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eh" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ei" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ej" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
  rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed

Else
rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
 chk.Value = True


End If

Next chk

   Case Else   'box is not checked
   chk.Enabled = True
      rngD.ClearContents
      rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Select
```

Thanks for help!

Comment: You submit a bit too much code to decipher what your trying to fix. Try just placing some break points in your code and create a few watch variables and the issue should be obvious.
Offhand I don't like your comparison to "vbnullstring" which has specific meaning. You may be needing to check against "Is Nothing" instead or an empty string (all have different meanings)

Comment: "Is Nothing" would check if the object doesn't exist. An empty string is very similar to vbnullstring with only a minute difference (that only affects a very very very small subset of procedures, for the most part they are nearly indiscernible).

Comment: The number of times you use an Or statement will make your code quite difficult to debug in the long run. Additionally, you may be having an issue with your use of an instantiated "chk" which is the variable that starts the condition. You then override this variable using the for...next loop. Use a separate checkbox variable for your loop. This is especially true if you expect the if statement to operate on the value of the initial chck, and not the checkboxes you are looping on.

Comment: @BrandonBarney Yes, I know that my if statements are not really good but i don't know how to do it in other way. Separate checkbox it's not good idea because i generate 1000 checkboxes so that will be so long code :D

Comment: @Ttrx I think you misunderstand what I mean by declaring a separate checkbox. You dont need one for each checkbox, you just need a variable that can be used as a control variable for the loop. Just as you currently have "chk" declared, you should declare something as simple as "CheckLoop" and then write your loop as "For each CheckLoop...". This is important, since otherwise your initial "chk" is getting repeatedly overwritten by your loop.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be with the Case statement.  You may need to adjust it to say:

```
Select Case chk.Value
Case Is = 1
```

instead of

```
Case 1
```

when checking against the value of chk

Comment: That shouldnt be an issue. As far as I am aware, both statements would operate in the same way.

Comment: I've had the (recent) unfortunate experience of having it compile with both, but skip over conditions when not using the "Is" .. not sure if its useful here, but it was on my mind and was the first thing noticed.

Comment: Unfortunately it isn't solution

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: The following code is most probably not what you want, but it might help you get there.

```
Sub CheckBoxDate()
    ' 17 Apr 2017

    Dim Ws As Worksheet
    Dim Chk As CheckBox
    Dim DateShift As Long               ' shift number of columns to the right for date
    Dim Rng As Range
    Dim RngColor As Long
    Dim Clms As String

    DateShift = 0
    Set Ws = Sheets("MA Template_VBack-End")

    ' This line of code has wrong syntax: What do you want?
    ' Set Chk = Ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)
    Set Chk = Ws.CheckBoxes("Check Box 4")
    ' Chk.TopLeftCell is already a range object: no need to re-define it
    Set Rng = Chk.TopLeftCell.Offset(0, DateShift)

    Chk.Value = 1                       ' default
    RngColor = vbGreen

    Clms = "C,D,E,F,G,I,T,U,Z,AB,AC,AP,AT,BS,BT,BU"
    If IsNullString(Clms, Chk.TopLeftCell.Row, Ws) Then
        Chk.Value = -4146               ' not checked
        RngColor = 16777215             ' no color
    End If
    Clms = "BV,BX,BZ,CA,CC,CE,CI,CK,CL,CM,CN,CO,CP,CQ,CS,EA,ED,EE,EG,EH,EI,EJ"
    If IsNullString(Clms, Chk.TopLeftCell.Row, Ws) Then
        Chk.Value = -4146               ' not checked
        RngColor = vbRed
    End If


    Rng.EntireRow.Interior.Color = RngColor
    ' Chk.Enabled = True                ' can't tell the intention of this
    ' Rng.ClearContents                 ' can't tell when this should be done
End Sub

Private Function IsNullString(Clms As String, _
                              R As Long, _
                              Ws As Worksheet) As Boolean
    ' 17 Apr 2017

    Dim C() As String
    Dim i As Integer

    C = Split(Clms, ",")
    For i = UBound(C) To 0 Step -1
        If Ws.Cells(R, Columns(C(i)).Column).Value = vbNullString Then Exit For
    Next i
    IsNullString = (i = Not True)
End Function
```

There are many parts of your code which are simply not understandable. Therefore I have tried to bring a concept to your idea which is understandable and can, therefore, perhaps be modified to do what you want.

The problem I found was that you are both asking the Value of your checkboxes and setting their Value. That can only work under very strictly controlled conditions, which don't exist. Therefore my code tries to bring an order to the action. First, set a default. Then make changes to the default. I think you might want to make changes only under specific conditions. The above code will allow you to easily do that.

The code can also easily be put into a loop to go through all the checkboxes in your sheet. I intentionally didn't try to implement that because it should be done only after a single loop works successfully, including the method of calling which assuredly doesn't work the way you programmed it. Also, the range you want coloured appear ill defined.

I hope you will find the little function I added helpful. It takes a lot of volume out of your code and also works faster because it doesn't need to check all the columns: if one NullString is found the condition is already met. I suggest you try to modify this code to meet more of your requirements and then, perhaps, come back with another question to fine-tune the final result.

Comment: I will respond for first question about Ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller) I have in my sheet like 1.000 checkbox'es so i can't define like u just one.

Comment: Chk.Value = 1                       ' default
It's couldnt be a default value - because in general all checkboxes will be unchecked and after review someone will be checking

'' Chk.Enabled = True                ' can't tell the intention of this'
My idea was to disable/enable checkboxes depends of if Statements (when any of required cells are empty then disable checkbox if not then enable

Comment: If Ws.Cells(R, Columns(C(i)).Column).Value = vbNullString Then - this makes error 1004 - application defined or object - defined error

Comment: To be more clear what i want to achieve by this code:
1. I need to validate for instance 100 lines from row 140 to 240 by checking checkboxes
2. If I check checkbox and every column in this row (which i require) is not empty then I allow to check and mark row as green
3. If I check checkbox and one of column which i require in row is empty then i disable checbox(or disable) and row is white (default color)

Comment: Did you mean to declare "Clms" as an array? As is, it is just a string and likely wont loop as you intend it to.

Comment: Sorry about the function call. I have amended the above code to specify a Row as argument for the function. `If IsNullString(Clms, Chk.TopLeftCell.Row, Ws) Then` in both instances.

Comment: OK. We got that out of the way then: To "uncheck" a checkmark or to "disable" it are two different cans of beer. I now understand that you aren't talking about disabling. The second point is also clarified between your lines, or so it seems: you mean to call the macro when you set a checkbox. Is that right?

Comment: This is going to be a 10-page correspondence. Sorry, I won't go for it. I will help you set up a system here and then it must be one question at a time. I shall post another answer with just the blueprint of your project. Then it's up to you to nurture it to realisation.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks so much for your help and lots of words which help me find my mistakes and also you teach me a lot things about VBA.

The way which solve my problem (maybe it's not the best, according to @Variatus I could do this much better, but I need more practices to understand VBA)

Working code:

```
Select Case chk.Value
   Case Is = 1   'box is checked
   If ws.Range("C" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("D" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("E" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("f" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("g" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("i" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("t" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("u" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("z" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ab" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ac" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ap" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("at" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bt" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bu" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
   rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed

 ElseIf ws.Range("bv" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bx" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("bz" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ca" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cc" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cd" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ce" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ci" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ck" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cl" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cm" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cn" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("co" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cp" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cq" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("cs" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
    chk.Value = False
 rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    ElseIf ws.Range("ea" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ed" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ee" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eg" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("eh" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ei" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Or ws.Range("ej" & chk.TopLeftCell.Row).Value = vbNullString Then
 chk.Value = False
  rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed

Else
rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen



End If

   Case Else   'box is not checked
   chk.Enabled = True
      rngD.ClearContents
      rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End Select
```

Scenario:
 1. Checked checkbox - row is green and checkbox checked
 2. Unchecked Checkbox - row is default color and checkbox is unchecked
 3. Required cell in row is empty - unchecked checkbox, row is red

Thanks so much for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my stab at it. From what I can tell, part of your problem may be in how you are approaching dynamic updates. I noticed, in rewriting your code, that you have this little tidbit here:

```
Set rngD = ws.Cells(lRow, lColChk + lColD)
```

If my hunch is correct, you are thinking of this as a formula. Worth noting here, once this reference is set, it isnt going to change it's target as the variables used to set it change. So for example, if lRow is 5, you set rngD, and then lRow changes to 6 rngD will still be pointing at row 5.

I could be mistaken, but this may be part of the issue.

See my version of your code below:

```
Sub CheckBoxDate()
Dim lColD As Long
lColD = 0 'number of columns to the right for date

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("MA Template_VBack-End")

Dim chk As CheckBox
Set chk = ws.CheckBoxes(Application.Caller)

Dim lRow As Long
lRow = chk.TopLeftCell.Row

Dim lColChk As Long
lColChk = chk.TopLeftCell.Column

' From what I can tell, you want this to dynamically update the row. As is, it will only ever be this row.
' Set rngD = ws.Cells(lRow, lColChk + lColD)

Dim ColArray_1 As Variant
ColArray_1 = Array("C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "I", "T", "U", "Z", "AB", "AC", "AP", "AT", "BS", "BT", "BU")

Dim ColArray_2 As Variant
ColArray_2 = Array("BV", "BX", "BZ", "CA", "CC", "CD", "CE", "CI", "CK", "CL", "CM", "CN", "CO", "CP", "CQ", "CS")

Dim ColArray_3 As Variant
ColArray_3 = Array("EA", "ED", "EE", "EQ", "EH", "EI", "EJ")

Dim col As Variant
Dim LoopRow As Long
Dim LoopCheck As CheckBox
Dim ConditionCheck As Boolean

Dim rngD As Range

If chk.value = 1 Then
    For Each LoopCheck In ws.CheckBoxes
        ConditionCheck = False

        LoopRow = chk.TopLeftCell.Row
        For Each col In ColArray_1
            If ws.Range(col & LoopRow).value = vbNullString Then
                LoopCheck.value = False
                Set rngD = ws.Cells(LoopRow, lColChk + lColD)
                rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
                ConditionCheck = True
                Exit For
        Next
        If Not ConditionCheck Then
                For Each col In ColArray_2
                If ws.Range(col & LoopRow).value = vbNullString Then
                    LoopCheck.value = False
                    Set rngD = ws.Cells(LoopRow, lColChk + lColD)
                    rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    ConditionCheck = True
                    Exit For
                Next
        End If
        If Not ConditionCheck Then
                For Each col In ColArray_3
                If ws.Range(col & LoopRow).value = vbNullString Then
                    LoopCheck.value = False
                    Set rngD = ws.Cells(LoopRow, lColChk + lColD)
                    rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
                    ConditionCheck = True
                    Exit For
                Next
        End If
        If Not ConditionCheck Then
            Set rngD = ws.Cells(LoopRow, lColChk + lColD)
            rngD.EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbGreen
            chk.value = True
        End If
    Next
Else
    LoopCheck.Enabled = True
    rngD.ClearContents
    rngD.EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone
End If
End Sub
```

I use loops to overcome the otherwise really ugly and incredibly bug prone Or statements. In this case, as soon as it finds something that meets the condition it will set the format and move on. This also demonstrates how you set a single control variable for looping. Also worth noting that the third and fourth loops have the same effect on the rows, so you could merge these, and merge ColArray's 2 and 3 as well.

I can't test this code since I dont have your worksheet and CheckBox doesn't show up in Intellisense for me (at least not when I declare the variables, I can see the methods that belong to it). Hopefully it does the trick for you though, or at least gets us closer.

Answer (score 0):

As promised in my comments above, this is intended as an indirect solution, a way to get at the questions in an orderly and timely fashion, such as determining the method of calling your procedure before writing it. Much of what you have already done can be incorporated eventually. Those code snippets can be added in this "procedure" as concepts are replaced with code and questions with decisions. My point here is to create a blueprint which will lead to questions that can be researched and answered and keep you on a clear path to success.

```
Private Sub ProjectPlan()
        ' 18 Apr 2017

        Dim Ws As Worksheet
        Dim Chk As CheckBox

    '    Set Ws = Sheets("MA Template_VBack-End")
        Set Ws = Sheets("Ttrx")

        ' determine how to call this procedure
        ' create and test the calling process
        ' ===== my inclination is to say that you will need ActiveX controls for that =====

        ' Create a macro to set the OnAction property of all checkboxes
        ' in the worksheet to point to this procedure. (don't do this manually: unreliable)
        ' determine whether to run the proc manually or with one of
        ' the worksheet events (such as Open or Save)

        ' You will need to have access to the clicked Chk object
        ' assign a meaningful name to this Chk
        ' test setting its Value property

        ' I presume that you will want to know the row in the
        ' worksheet on which the Chk was clicked.
        ' ===== Could there be more than 1 Chk in a row? =====
        ' create the functionality and test it
        ' assign a meaningful variable name to this important row

        ' Define the range in this row which would be subject to coloring
        ' Assign a meaningful name to this range

        ' Determine colours: Default = no colour, Check = Green, Uncheck = Red
        ' devise a method by which to create all THREE colours
        ' ===== How will you create 3 colours with True & False? =====
        ' test the system you have devised on one Chk

        ' test colouring the range you have determined by the system
        ' you have devised: one Chk only at this time, meaning one row only.

        ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        ' Create a written description of your basic system,
          ' if you haven't done so already
          ' Resolve these problems:-
        ' 1. When the sheet is loaded it is white, red and green as saved (correct?)
             ' You might change that status using the Workbook Open event.
        ' 2. When a Chk is clicked it changes from True to False or v.v. (of course)
             ' ===== This action calls the macro (correct?)
        ' 3. Then the macro evaluates certain cells in the same row
             ' ==== Does it change the Chk to something else? ====
        ' 4. Then the macro looks at the final setting of the Chk
             ' and colours the row according to the Chk.Value
             ' ==== But the Chk has only True & False, red and green.
             ' ==== When to colour white?
        ' The way I understand your idea now is that checking the Chk
          ' indicates your wish to check which results in red or green colouring
          ' while the Chk.Value is actually revised by the code.
          ' ==== Careful not to create a loop where the change made by the code
                 ' calls the same procedure. =====
          ' If your intention is to just check and colour, returning the
            ' Chk to unchecked in every case, consider using a button instead.
          ' Either way, it isn't clear how you can return a row to "no colour"
            ' unless you remove all colouring on Save or Close or Open.

        ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

        ' You seem to want to loop through all Chks in the worksheet
        ' whenever one of the Chks is clicked. ===== Is that correct? =====
             ' This will be very, very slow.
             ' Consider not checking the entire sheet on every click.

        ' Create a loop to call other Chks you want to call
          ' test the loop first with one, then with 2, then 3 Chks

        ' Any mopping up to do?
        ' Consider returning certain cells to their original, colourless state
        ' only after the program has run its course.
          ' This is an alternative to doing so before it runs.
    End Sub
```